# Can "unto" be used instead of "onto" in American English?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, american-english

Is there a difference in how the preposition "onto" is used in British and American English? I always understood it to match the following dictionary definition I found online, and was not aware of any difference in American English:

> to a place or position on

In a side discussion on a different Stack Exchange site, another poster made the following claim:

> **Onto** is English, whereas **Unto** is American English.

The expression that sparked this was "climb unto a pedestal". I suggested that the proper expression was "climb onto a pedestal". While it was a pointless discussion in the context, I still want to know which one is correct in American English.

Comment: I think the idea of a US/UK split here is almost certainly spurious.

Comment: *"Do onto others as others would do onto you?"* I don't think so. In both AmE and BrE, *onto* and *unto* mean different things. And  pedestals are climbed *onto*.

Comment: @PeterShor In Norfolk they have an exclamation, when surprised by something 'Good gracious onto me!' I have never worked it out and have never heard it anywhere else.

Comment: [*"Suffer the little children to come **onto** me"*](http://biblehub.com/luke/18-16.htm) evokes the image of dozens of kids piling on top of Jesus in some bizarre kind of "play fight".

Comment: Don't use unto ever. Unless you're quoting KJV.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, What about "woe onto me" vs "woe unto me"?

Comment: @Pacerier: Idiomatically it's usually [Woe **is** me!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=woe+unto+me%2Cwoe+onto+me%2Cwoe+is+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwoe%20unto%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoe%20is%20me%3B%2Cc0) Or *was*, I should say, since all variants are at least "dated", if not actually archaic. But note that *Woe **unto** me!* does/did occur fairly often, whereas nobody ever said *Woe **onto** me!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted the two prepositions have different meanings, and according to Goole ( see Ngram below) their usage is similar both in US and UK. *You climb onto a a pedestal both in US and UK.*

[Onto](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Onto) prep:

> - On top of; to a position on; upon: The dog jumped onto the chair
> - Informal Fully aware of; informed about: The police are onto the robbers' plans.

[Unto](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unto) prep:

> - To.
> - Until: a fast unto death.
> - By: a place unto itself, quite unlike its surroundings.

[Ngram AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onto%2Cunto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunto%3B%2Cc0): onto, unto.

[Ngram BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onto%2Cunto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunto%3B%2Cc0): onto, unto.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: You might think *"onto"* is a new word from the Ngrams. It's not; 100 years ago it was spelled *"on to"*.

Comment: @PeterShor, That is so *according to one analysis*.